# PHP mailer with SQL to send email on specific row

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I'm not using everyday php, html, css, but I know the basics in this programming languages.
I want to send an email on specified row from a button. (I attached a picture with index page of my script and marked with red the button)

[index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOLhR.png)

For the moment the code the code send emails to all rows, no matter which button I press.
Can someone explain me how can I do to send email from button only on specified row?

My code is:

```
<?php
require "config.php";
require "common.php";

try {
  $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks";

  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();

  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
} catch(PDOException $error) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO oldtasks SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = :id; DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = :id;";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $statement->execute();
    
    $task = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
  }
}
?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
    foreach ($result as $row) :
    $responsabil = $row['responsabil'];
    $produs = $row['produs'];
    $prob_recl = $row['prob_recl'];
    $cauza = $row['cauza'];
    $act_impl = $row['act_impl'];
    $termen = $row['termen'];
    
    $from = "tasks@plastec-romania.ro";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $to      = $responsabil;
    $subject = 'Reminder - '  .$produs ;
    
    $message = "Reminder: \n\nProdus: " . $produs . "\nProblema reclamata: " . $prob_recl . "\nCauza: " . $cauza . "\nActiuni de implementat: " . $act_impl . "\nTermen: " . $termen . "\n\nTasks: http://192.168.0.8/tasks";   
    
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    endforeach;
}
?>
<title>Plan de măsuri şi acţiuni - Task manager</title>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>
<table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px" style="font-weight: bold;">Document:</td>
        <td width="100px" align="right">QS01-323</td>
        <td rowspan="8" align="center" style="font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #C1CBD1;">Plan de masuri</td>
        <td rowspan="8" align="center" width="300px"><img src="img/logo.png" width="290px"></img></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px" style="font-weight: bold;">Versiune:</td>
        <td width="100px" align="right">07</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px" style="font-weight: bold;">Pagina:</td>
        <td width="100px" align="right">1 din 1</td>

    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px" style="font-weight: bold;">Data:</td>
        <td width="100px" align="right">20.02.2021</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<p align="center">
    <span style="padding-right: 150px;"><a href="create.php"><strong><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Adauga un task nou</strong></a></span>
    <span><a href="completed.php"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i> Task-uri inchise</a></span>
</p>
<table border="1px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="0" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; background-color: #C1CBD1;">ID</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><br />Prioritate</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fab fa-product-hunt"></i><br />Produs</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i><br />Problema reclamata</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-briefcase-medical"></i><br />Cauza</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><br />Actiuni de implementat</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i><br />Responsabil email</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i><br />Termen</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i><br />Progres</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><br />Responsabil verificare</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i><br />Data verficarii</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i><br />Eficienta</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><br />Edit</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i><br />Complete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="0" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"><?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="5%" class="importanta<?php echo escape($row["importanta"]); ?>"></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["produs"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["prob_recl"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["cauza"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["act_impl"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["responsabil"]); ?><br />
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send details to embassy" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><?php echo escape($row["termen"]); ?></td>
            <td width="5%">
                <progress max="100" value="<?php echo escape($row["progres"]); ?>" class="v<?php echo escape($row["progres"]); ?>"></progress><br /><center><?php echo escape($row["progres"]); ?>%</center>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["resp_verifica"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><?php echo escape($row["data_verificarii"]); ?></td>
            <td width="5%">
                <progress max="100" value="<?php echo escape($row["eficienta"]); ?>" class="v<?php echo escape($row["eficienta"]); ?>"></progress><br /><center><?php echo escape($row["eficienta"]); ?>%</center>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="update-single.php?id=<?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="?id=<?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?>"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code relevant to your problem, belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted. Do not just dump it onto an external platform.

Comment: You need to start by passing a specific row id with your button. And then you need to either select only the record with that ID from the database to begin with, or if you still want to loop over all records for some reason, inside the loop only send the mail when the id of the current records, matches the id you submitted via the form.

Comment: Could you please show me an example? I understand that at this row "foreach ($result as $row) :" to add the ID row from database, right?

Comment: Maybe something like `<input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" />`, and then use that value in the PHP, to decide which row to get from the database, and then only send an email for that one row.

Comment: And the ID value will be used in "if" or at "foreach"?

Comment: No it would be used in a SELECT query to find the correct record in the database

Comment: I have the SELECT query in the code  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks" and inserted the  row ID tin input field, but still sending to all rows when I press any button... So, I think in the if function before foreach to add the row ID, no?

Comment: You need a second query within `if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))`, e.g. `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE ID = :id` so that you can select only the data for the one which needs email sending. Your `SELECT * FROM tasks` query is for the purpose of displaying the list in the page. You don't re-use it for this different task because it isn't suitable.

Comment: Ok, I do the SELECT query but now how can I add the ID in foreach? foreach ($result as $row) :

Comment: You don't need the foreach. Just get the one record returned from this new query, and use it directly. That's what I've been saying the whole time.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, but how can I define de indexes for mail send? for example the $to for mail send I want to be from database from column "responsabil".

Comment: They will come from the result of your `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE ID = :id` query, obviously.

Comment: I understand this, but I receive error Notice: Undefined index: responsabil in C:\Sites\tasks\index.php on line 39, and the line 39 I changed into this: $responsabil = $_GET['responsabil'];, and I have for $to      = $responsabil;

Comment: `$_GET` reads from the request's querystring, not from your database query. You seem to be missing quite a lot of basic knowledge. It's strange because you seem to have written quite a lot of other working code (as shown above) to interact with databases. Or maybe you didn't write that code? Anyway something like `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` will get the row from your SELECT statement after you've executed. $row will be an array containing all the data returned from the query (because it should only return 1 row).

Comment: e.g. maybe `if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = :id";  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql); $statement = $connection->bindValue(":id", $_POST["button_pressed"]);  $statement->execute(); $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $to = $row['responsabil'];` ...etc. ($responsabil itself seems to be redundant - it isn't re-used later).

Comment: I solved the issue, I posted as answer the full code.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.
Bellow is the code if someone needs.

```
<?php
require "config.php";
require "common.php";

try {
  $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks";

  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();

  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
} catch(PDOException $error) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO oldtasks SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = :id; DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = :id;";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $statement->execute();
    
    $task = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
  }
}
?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['button_pressed'])) 
{
    try {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        $id = $_POST['button_pressed'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = :id;";
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
        $statement->execute();
        
        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    
    $responsabil = $row['responsabil'];
    $produs = $row['produs'];
    $prob_recl = $row['prob_recl'];
    $cauza = $row['cauza'];
    $act_impl = $row['act_impl'];
    $termen = $row['termen'];
    
    $from = "tasks@plastec-romania.ro";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $to      = $responsabil;
    $subject = 'Reminder - '  .$produs ;
    
    $message = "Reminder: \n\nProdus: " . $produs . "\nProblema reclamata: " . $prob_recl . "\nCauza: " . $cauza . "\nActiuni de implementat: " . $act_impl . "\nTermen: " . $termen . "\n\nTasks: http://192.168.0.8/tasks";   
    
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
<title>Plan de măsuri şi acţiuni - Task manager</title>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>
<table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px" style="font-weight: bold;">Document:</td>
        <td width="100px" align="right">QS01-323</td>
        <td rowspan="8" align="center" style="font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #C1CBD1;">Plan de masuri</td>
        <td rowspan="8" align="center" width="300px"><img src="img/logo.png" width="290px"></img></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px" style="font-weight: bold;">Versiune:</td>
        <td width="100px" align="right">07</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px" style="font-weight: bold;">Pagina:</td>
        <td width="100px" align="right">1 din 1</td>

    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100px" style="font-weight: bold;">Data:</td>
        <td width="100px" align="right">20.02.2021</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<p align="center">
    <span style="padding-right: 150px;"><a href="create.php"><strong><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Adauga un task nou</strong></a></span>
    <span><a href="completed.php"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i> Task-uri inchise</a></span>
</p>
<table border="1px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="0" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; background-color: #C1CBD1;">ID</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><br />Prioritate</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fab fa-product-hunt"></i><br />Produs</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i><br />Problema reclamata</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-briefcase-medical"></i><br />Cauza</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><br />Actiuni de implementat</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i><br />Responsabil email</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i><br />Termen</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i><br />Progres</th>
            <th width="10%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><br />Responsabil verificare</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i><br />Data verficarii</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i><br />Eficienta</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><br />Edit</th>
            <th width="5%" style="background-color: #C1CBD1"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i><br />Complete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="0" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"><?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="5%" class="importanta<?php echo escape($row["importanta"]); ?>"></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["produs"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["prob_recl"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["cauza"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["act_impl"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["responsabil"]); ?><br />
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send details to embassy" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><?php echo escape($row["termen"]); ?></td>
            <td width="5%">
                <progress max="100" value="<?php echo escape($row["progres"]); ?>" class="v<?php echo escape($row["progres"]); ?>"></progress><br /><center><?php echo escape($row["progres"]); ?>%</center>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><?php echo escape($row["resp_verifica"]); ?></td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><?php echo escape($row["data_verificarii"]); ?></td>
            <td width="5%">
                <progress max="100" value="<?php echo escape($row["eficienta"]); ?>" class="v<?php echo escape($row["eficienta"]); ?>"></progress><br /><center><?php echo escape($row["eficienta"]); ?>%</center>
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="update-single.php?id=<?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="?id=<?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?>"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Glad it's solved now. Just a note about the logic of `} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }` though...if your query fails you'll output the exception message (which itself isn't very secure in a live system, it should be logged instead), but, even though there's a critical failure, your code just carries on below that and tries to create the email anyway. But obviously it would fail because $row won't be defined, and so it will also produce other errors and warnings. This isn't a robust approach to handling database errors.

Comment: Also I don't know why you created `$connection` again? It's already created in the first part of the script. You don't need a separate connection for each query.

Comment: Thank you. This code is used in limited connections, only in local company LAN. I have now created the script, and after it can be used, no one will change it :))

Comment: `This code is used in limited connections, only in local company LAN` sorry I'm not sure why you think this is relevant to anything I've said? Can you explain? Writing secure and robust code is not limited to internet-facing applications. Every application should be written that way. You cannot assume that users and devices within your LAN will never be a threat.

Comment: It won't be accessed via public IP. Works only on LAN with internal IP.

Comment: That's irrelevant. I'll repeat:  Writing secure and robust code is not limited only to internet-facing applications. **Every** application should be written in a secure way. You cannot assume that users and devices within your LAN will never be a threat. And also, your users should not have to suffer from your logic bugs either.